# Ignoring an output with grep

Tags: grep

I am currently using grep to locate a string in a file. However, I get a result I do not want.

Example output:

```
user@user:~/tmp$ grep "z=" note > tmp.txt | cat tmp.txt 
z=0.016728
 S_1.4 GHz=   1597.61548     mJy, for L_1.4=1E24 W Hz^-1 (index=0.8)
```

I do not want to use grep to ignore all results after z=0.016728 because I cannot guarantee that the file structure I am using will always have z= before GHz=.

I would like to ignore anything without a newline or with a character value before z=.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the sample you have given, the simplest option would be to *anchor* the expression to the start of a line:

```
grep '^z=' note
```

Alternatively, you could match only after a *word boundary*:

```
grep '\bz=` note
```

See [Start of String and End of String Anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) and [Word Boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Answer (score 1):

Reread `man grep`, and use Extended `grep` with a simple Regular expression (and single quotes to avoid shell expandion always):

```
grep -E '^z=' note
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks. I read man grep, but I must've missed that part.

Comment: Few seconds quicker than me. However, the `-E` is not needed. `^` works with basic regex as well.